# Get array of entries based of catagory

Tags: categories, channel, php

I'd like to start editing a template, the template uses php to create an array. Is their documentation about how to only get an array for a certain category? Or are they channels? Sorry.

I can't modify the code too much, but simply need to get the entries from an archive category / channel.

```
    <h2><span>Selected Projects</span></h2>
  <ul id="project_list">
  <?php foreach ($entries_query->result_array() as $entry): ?>  <li>
      <h3><a href="/projects/<?= $entry['url_title'] ?>/"><?= $entry['title'] ?></a></h3>
      <?php if ($entry['rollover_image']): ?>
        {exp:imgsizer:size image="<?= str_replace('{filedir_1}', '/images/projects/', $entry['rollover_image']) ?>" width="320" alt="" quality="90"}
      <?php else: ?>
        {exp:imgsizer:size image="<?= $images[$entry['entry_id']] ?>" width="320" alt="" quality="90"}
      <?php endif; ?>
      <ul><?php 
        foreach ($categories_query->result_array() as $cat):
          if ($cat['entry_id'] == $entry['entry_id']) {
            echo '<li><span class="'.$cat['cat_url_title'].'">'.$cat['name'].'</span></li>';
          }
        endforeach; 
      ?></ul>
    </li>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the PHP code for populating the entries of category/categories, you should use the channel entry tag like:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="CHANNEL_NAME" category="CATEGORY_ID"}
    <P>{title}</P>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

take a reference from here to get list of all the parameters and variables to be used with channel entry tag.

http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html